Guest PayPal Express Checkout for downloadable products doesn't work
I'm using Magento 2.4.7-p1 and I'm not able to make guest checkout for downloadable products works paying through PayPal Express Checkout.
The message error says: Failed address validation: %1

It works for simple products but not for downloadable one.
I tried to set all the options as described here on the official docs but it still doesn't work.

For it to work you must set "Disable Guest Checkout if Cart Contains Downloadable Items" to "No" and "Sharable" to "Yes" in the Downloadable Product Options
Of course "Allow Guest Checkout" must also be "Yes" in the Sales -> Checkout -> Checkout Options.
If the problem still persists I think you may be experiencing a bug in the PayPal module in Magento. The work around is to disable the In-Context checkout experience. In Sales -> Payment Methods -> PayPay Express Checkout -> Configure, Set "Enable In-Context Checkout Experience" to "No".
The bug occurred for us when we had some products we wanted to be checked out as guest and some that required an account. If you want all products to be able to use Guest checkout setting the options above should fix it. But see if In-Context checkout makes a difference.
I haven't reported the bug to magento github because it always seems so futile.
